# Recording arguments and return values from python functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

I want to record all returned values from functions with specific arguments to mock some objects with real data.

Is there a good way to do that? I see I can get function arguments with mock calls, but not the return value.

Comment: Are you talking about using `unittest.mock()`?

Comment: If so, does `mock = Mock(); mock.return_value = 3; mock()` do the trick, or are you looking for something else?